# How to concatenate files, rule out empty ones?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I need to paste a lot of `.txt` files together. I use this command:

```
cat *.txt > newfile.txt
```

I noticed that some of these files are empty. How can I insert a control in the script to prevent that the `cat` from acting on these empty files?

Thank you.

Comment: If they're empty why does it matter they are included?

Comment: Also note that if `newfile.txt` already existed at the point  the command was run, you _could_ end up with a situation that `cat` included `newfile.txt` in its list from `*.txt` and kept reading from it and writing to it at the same time

Comment: @roaima, d'oh, yes of course. GNU cat actually complains about that, btw: `cat: newfile.txt: input file is output file`.

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, but you can't guarantee GNU `cat`, hence the warning

Comment: @roaima, no, indeed you can't. I was just surprised to notice that, hence the "btw". With busybox, I got what seemed an unbounded loop. :)

Comment: Empty files have no content, so `cat`-ing them produces no output. So the result of concatenation of a set of files, including empty ones, should be exactly the same as the result of concateantion of the same set of files, excluding empty ones. So what's the reason to complicate?

Comment: @roaima, **no**! Running `command > file` does *delete* `file`, creates it anew and then starts  `command`.  So e.g. `cat one one one > one` just nets you an empty file (clobber  `one`, then copy three copies of it --nothing-- to `one`).

Comment: @vonbrand I don't see any delete action for `command >file`, I only see truncation. On that basis with anything other than GNU `cat` the following will cause an infinitely growing file. (1) preparation: `p=$(ps -ef); wc=$(wc -c <<<"$p"); n=$(( 10000 / wc )); while [[ $((n--)) -ge 0 ]]; do echo "$p"; done > a1; for i in 2 3 4; do cp a1 a$i; done; touch newfile` (2) execution: `cat a? newfile > newfile`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not really necessary, but if you need to rule out empty files:

```
for i in *.txt; do [ "$i" != newfile.txt ] && [ -s "$i" ] && cat -- "$i"; done >newfile.txt
```

The `-s` test will be true if the given file exists and is not empty (this is a standard test; see `man test`). We also avoid processing the output file itself.

Comment: Note that this will append to the file if run multiple times (it's not idempotent); add a `truncate -s0 newfile.txt;` at the beginning if this is undesired.

Comment: @Caagr98, it should be idempotent, as the first thing that's done there is the `>newfile.txt` redirection which truncates the file. However, `newfile.txt` will be included in the expansion of `*.txt`, and if it's not the first to be processed, you will either get an error from some cat implementations that the input is the same as the output, or you'll get an infinite loop filling up the disk (at least if the previous files were larger than a few kb).

Comment: Oh, I see your comment is probably referring to the version before @Kusalananda's edit. Before the edit, the problem would have happened after the second run indeed. The edit makes it occur every time, so I'd say it's not a valid edit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sorry for the botched edit. Will correct. (now fixed)

Comment: This is a very, very good answer. It does not only provide the answer, but this method I didn't consider!  +1.

Answer (score 4):

In `zsh`, you'd use the `L+0` glob qualifier:

```
(cat -- *.txt(n-.L+0)) > newfile.txt
```

(here, also limiting to *regular* files only (`.`) determined (as well as the size) after symlink resolution (`-`), and sorting the list of files numerically (`n`) so `file10.txt` comes *after* `file9.txt` for instance).

Normally, including empty files shouldn't make a difference, as `cat` on an empty file produces no output. There are however two things that make it a good idea:

1. You don't want `newfile.txt` itself to be included in the list of files to pass to `cat`. Some `cat` implementations will complain if the input file is the same as where stdout go to. And with those that  don't you could end up filling up your disk as `cat` would read the output file in a loop. Here, the glob is expanded after the redirection is performed. That redirection truncates the output file, so it will have a size of 0 at the time that glob is expanded.
2. By removing unnecessary files from the list of arguments passed to `cat`, we make the command line shorter, so we make it less likely to reach the limit on its size. Though here, you could also work around the problem by using `zsh`'s `zargs`.

Without `zsh`, but if you have GNU utilities, you could do something equivalent with:

```
 LC_ALL=C find -L . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' ! -name '.*' \
                    ! -name newfile.txt -type f -size +0 -print0 |
   sort -V0 |
   xargs -r0 cat > newfile.txt
```

Here, we can't rely on `-size +0`, as if there are many many files in the current directory, `xargs` could end up running one `cat` with a first batch before `find` gets to check the size of `newfile.txt` (also here, `xargs > newfile.txt` and `find` are run concurrently, so the redirection may not have been performed by the time `find` starts and checks the size of `newfile.txt` if it existed beforehand).

We also need to exclude hidden files by hand as `find` doesn't do it by default. We also need `LC_ALL=C` to work around GNU `find`'s issues with non-characters. In this case, `xargs` will work around the limit of the command line size.

The equivalences with the `zsh` approach are:

- `-L` ⟷ `-`
- `-type f` ⟷ `.`
- `-size +0` ⟷ `L+0`
- `sort -V` ⟷ `n`

Answer (score 0):

As in classic UNIX filesystems the overhead to read an empty file is just about the same as detecting that the file is empty, it makes little sense to treat empty files separate, significantly when `cat`-ing them.

Also you did not tell whether the files would have to be in order.
If not (maybe find even preserves the order here), this may be more efficient than https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/633734/320598:

`(find *.txt \! -size 0 | xargs cat) >newfile.txt`

Comment: Using `find . -prune -type f -name '*.txt' ! -name newfile.txt ! -size 0c -exec cat {} + >newfile.txt` would be safer and standard. With GNU `find`: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' ! -name newfile.txt ! -empty -exec cat {} + >newfile.txt`.  Note that `!` is not special when surrounded by spaces, at least not in a standard shell, not even in `bash`.

Comment: @Kusalanda, true, but that wouldn't `sort` the list of file names like `*.txt` does

Comment: Among the problems: there's (1) problems with filenames starting  with `-` causing `find` to treat them as option or predicate (2) if those `*.txt` files are or type directory, `find` will recurse into them (3) if some are symlinks, they will have a non-zero size even if the file they point to is empty (4) `find`'s output format is not compatible with `xargs`' input format. Here it will choke on whitespace, quotes, backslashes in filenames (5) `newfile.txt` could end up in the list of filenames passed to `cat` causing disk fill up.

Comment: Is the answer really worse than https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/633734/320598? YOu are invited to edit or suggest edits.